# ROC curve for a binary classifier in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, roc

I have a binary classifier, which classifies an input X as class zero if its predicted value is below some threshold (say `T`), and one otherwise.

I have all predicted and actual values for every input. So I can have both predicted class and actual class of an input.

Now I want to have the ROC curve for this classifier with MATLAB. How should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`perfcurve`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/perfcurve.html):

```
[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass);
plot(X,Y);
```

`labels` are the true labels of the data, `scores` are the output scores from your classifier (before the threshold) and `posclass` is the positive class in your labels.

Comment: What do `X` and `Y` represent?

Comment: @MatinKh X is false positive rate, Y is true positive rate by default. You can change them as well. Check this page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html

Comment: @MatinKh `X` and `Y` are the values for the axis of the ROC plot.

Comment: @Ran You have mentioned that scores are output scores from classifier before applying threshold. Then how do we apply threshold