# How can i calculate sensitivity(True positive rate) and specificity(True negative rate) using libsvm as a binary classifier in matlab?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am working on face verification problem.I am using LibSVM as a classifier. I want to calculate true positive rate and true negative rate.

By using these two performance measures, I want to calculate Equal error rate and also want to draw ROC curve.

I read about perfcurve command in matlab.But what here score means in command.??

Comment: Do you get a label vector as output from your classifier? Do you also have a ground truth label vector? You should be able to find the number of true positives and number of true negatives by comparing these two vectors.

Comment: @Cecilia yes i have both predicted label vector and original label vector. After that how can i findout TPR and TNR in matlab, as i also want to calculate Equal error rate using these two values and want to draw roc curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using libsvm, there are three possible return values from the `svmpredict` function.

```
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model [,'libsvm_options']);
```

If you don't specify that you want all the return values, by assigning the output to using several variables, you will only get the first variable, `predicted_label`.

If you want to produce an ROC curve, you need the classifier scores for each instance in order to calculate the thresholds. The scores are the `decision_values`.

You can then use either [`roc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/roc.html) or [`plotroc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotroc.html) from the Neural Network Toolkit or [`perfcurve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html) from the Machine Learning Toolkit to generate your ROC curve.

For the true positive and false positive rates at each threshold in the form of a cell array, use

```
[tpr,fpr,thresholds] = roc(ground_truth, decision_values);
```

For a plot of the ROC curve, use

```
plotroc(ground_truth, decision_values);
```

Or

```
[X,Y] = perfcurve(ground_truth, decision_values, positive_class_name);
plot(X,Y);
```

See [ROC curve for a binary classifier in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600568/roc-curve-for-a-binary-classifier-in-matlab) for another `perfcurve` example.

Comment: Thank you much for such a nice description. But in libsvm options does i need to specify '-b 1' ?

Comment: @Suru That depends. It is an optional parameter for the `svmpredict` method. You don't need it to train a classifier, but using it would change the output. I would recommend reading the [libsvm documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) to decide which additional options you want to use. If you decide to specify additional options, put them as a string in the `libsvm_options` optional parameter for the `svmpredict`function in Matlab. (Additional [Matlab documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README))

Comment: @Cecilia How will ROC be plotted with perfcurve because ROC is dependent upon the threshold values. How will threshold values are changing here?

Comment: @TariqS I'm not sure I understand your question. perfcurve plots an ROC curve by manipulating a threshold on the classifier scores. The ROC curve is created by plotting the true positive rate (TPR) against the false positive rate (FPR) at various threshold settings. Do you want to know what the threshold values are at each plotted point?

Comment: I am confused on determining the threshold value that how will it effect the TPR(sensitivity) and FPR(1-specificity)? I have calculated TPR and FPR as this:
TPR = TP/(TP+FN);
FPR = FP/(FP+TN);
And in this there is no threshold that is effecting it.  And I am calculating TPs and FPs . And also there is no threshold that is effecting TPs and FPs. Kindly guide me. It will be a great favor. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @TariqS The model produces a score (decision_values) for every sample, you must then threshold this score to decide if the model has predicted the positive or negative class. You can use a simple threshold of zero; then all positive scores are the positive class and all negative scores are the negative class. Or you can choose a more aggressive threshold. For example, decision_values > 0.5 is positive or decision_values > 1.0 is positive. When the threshold is less aggressive, recall will be higher. When the threshold is more aggressive, precision will be higher.

Comment: @Cecilia to define the class either positive or negative, I am using the labels 0 or 1 in the perfcurve command. I am just concern with the threshold value, how will it effect my ROC curve. I have calculated the TPR and FPR, and use it as decision_values. Basically, I have 12 videos and I have to build up their ROC curve on variable threshold.